# FileTable External Process Like Zip using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, file, t-sql

Has anyone ever tried to use tsql to launch external processes against files in a FileTable? I have not been able to find anything so if may not be possible.

In particular I am looking into PGP and ZIP operations. My backup plan is to use C# in combination with queries against the filetable.

I am curious to know if it can be done with T-SQL instead. I have looked at `xpcmdshell` to launch a process but many people recommend against this.

Thoughts and ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: A sql clr function or procedure is probably the way to go if you want to perform zip and encryption operations in T-SQL. The following github project by Wes Brown may help you get started. 
https://github.com/SQLServerIO/SQL-Server-File-System-Tools
While this particular project does not make use of FileTables it does perform basic compression and encryption on files which you could adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Can set folder to compressed (or on EFS)?

See http://blog.brucejackson.info/2013/04/sql-file-table-step-by-step.html